# Fibonacci infinite list performance (Higher order functions vs. Standard recursion)

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, fibonacci, higher-order-functions, infinite

While learning about infinite list creation in Haskell I found the following implementation of fibonacci using higher order functions (`zipWith`)

```hs
fibs :: [Integer]
fibs = 1:1:(zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))
```

Looks very clever but also too much abstraction for a beginner.

So, I decided to create the recursive solution of fibonacci that ended like this:

```hs
fib :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> a
fib n
  | (n == 0) = 1
  | (n == 1) = 1
  | (n > 1) = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

fib' :: (Num t, Ord t) => t -> [t]
fib' n = (fib n):(fib' (n+1))

fiblst :: [Integer]
fiblst = fib' 0
```

Both works, but I see really bad performance in my implementation, while the original (`fibs`) function goes at the speed of light and keeps printing the whole screen, mine (`fiblst`) on the other side hardly goes to the third line and keeps eating the CPU.

Any hints about why my implementation is so slow compared to the other ?

Thanks

Comment: tl;dr of the dupes: because `fib n` makes `2^n` recursive calls, `fibs` doesn't, and exponentials get really big really fast.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this related questions, they already answered !